# How do I make Java & Postgres enums work together for update?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

acttype is an enumcs so you can't insert it as a normal string
without casting it to an enumcs `INSERT INTO dir_act (actcode,actname,acttype,national_code) VALUES (?,?,?::enumcs,?)`

Where as for updating I tried with same typecasting as follows, but it does not worked.

```
update dir_act set actname=?,acttype=?::enumcs,national_code=? where actcode=?
```

Comment: it has to be `acttype=?` and in `prepared statement` cast it to `enum`

Comment: @ Ashish I did try with your solution but i got org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: type "enum" does not exist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can avoid the `toString()` on the Enum by doing this

```java
stmt.setObject(2,AnimalType.DOG,java.sql.Types.OTHER)
```

Works for JDBC driver PostgreSQL 42.2.5

Answer (score 31):

From JDBC's point-of-view, just treat the PostgreSQL enum like a string.

Quoting blog [Convert between Java enums and PostgreSQL enums](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/convert-between-java-enums-and-postgresql-enums/):

> PostgreSQL allows you to create enum types using the following syntax:
>
> ```sql
> CREATE TYPE animal_type AS ENUM('DOG', 'CAT', 'SQUIRREL');
> ```
>
> You can now use ‘animal’ as a datatype in your tables, for example:
>
> ```sql
> create table pet (                         
>     pet_id        integer         not null,
>     pet_type      animal_type     not null,
>     name          varchar(20)     not null
> );
> ```
>
> In Java, you’d have a corresponding enum type:
>
> ```java
> public enum AnimalType {
>     DOG,
>     CAT,
>     SQUIRREL;
> }
> ```
>
> Converting between Java and PostgreSQL enums is straightforward. For example, to insert or update an enum field you could use the CAST syntax in your SQL PreparedStatement:
>
> ```sql
> INSERT INTO pet (pet_id, pet_type, name) VALUES (?, CAST(? AS animal_type), ?);
>
> --or
>
> INSERT INTO pet (pet_id, pet_type, name) VALUES (?, ?::animal_type, ?);
> ```
>
> **Postgres will also let you insert/update an enum just by passing its value as a string.**
>
> Whether casting or not, the Java side is the same. You would set the fields like this:
>
> ```java
> stmt.setInt(1, 1);
> stmt.setString(2, AnimalType.DOG.toString());
> stmt.setString(3, 'Rex');
> ```
>
> Retrieving the enum from a SELECT statement looks like this:
>
> ```java
> AnimalType.valueOf(stmt.getString("pet_type"));
> ```
>
> Take into consideration that enums are case-sensitive, so any case mismatches between your Postgres enums and Java enums will have to be accounted for. Also note that the PostgreSQL enum type is non-standard SQL, and thus not portable.

Comment: Thank you for excellent explanation. However I believe it is a bug in Postgres JDBC driver: https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1420

Answer (score 11):

You have to define implicit conversion in Postgres along with your type definition, like below:

```
CREATE CAST (varchar AS animal_type) WITH INOUT AS IMPLICIT;
```

Than you can skip the explicit conversion in insert; so it works also with Spring Data JDBC and other libs that do generate insert query for you.

Comment: Great answer as this solves it in the DB level hence it works with any framework. Didn't even know about this auto cast feature of postgres before.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SpringJDBC, just provide `Types.OTHER` as explicit type using JdbcTemplate, for example:

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO dir_act (actcode,actname,acttype,national_code) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
Object[] arguments = new Object[]{"code", "name", Enum.Type, "nat_code"};
int[] argumentTypes = new int[]{Types.VARCHAR, Types.VARCHAR, Types.OTHER, Types.VARCHAR};

jdbcTemplate.update(sql, arguments, argumentTypes);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
private TypeEnum type;
```

```
public enum JobTypeEnum {
    A,
    B
}
```

```
create table public.my_table (
    id varchar(255) not null,
    "type" varchar(10) not null,
    constraint my_table primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: import javax.persistence.EnumType;
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;