# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "check_state" is of type check_state but expression is of type character varying

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, enums, spring-data-jdbc

I am using Spring Data JDBC in my project but I am having trouble persisting objects that have enum properties that correspond to Postgres enums in my database.

I have a PutMapping similar to this:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{buildingId}/rooms/{roomId}")
  public Room updateRoom(@PathVariable Long buildingId, @PathVariable Long roomId,
                         @RequestBody Set<Quad> quads) {
    Optional<Room> toUpdate = roomRepo.findById(roomId);
    if (toUpdate.isPresent()) {
      Room room = toUpdate.get();
      room.setQuads(quads);
      roomRepo.save(room);
      return room;
    } else {
      ...
    }

  }
```

With a Quad entity similar to this:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(value = "quads")
public class Quad {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  private Long roomId;

  private String quadLabel;

  private CheckState checkState;

  public Quad() {
    checkState = CheckState.UNCHECKED;
  }
}
```

With corresponding CheckState enum:

```
public enum CheckState {
  UNCHECKED,
  CHECKED_DAMAGED,
  CHECKED_INTACT,
  RECHECK_NEEDED,
}
```

However, when I try to send a PUT request to this endpoint with a body such as this:

```
{
  ...
  "checkState": "UNCHECKED",
  ...
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "check_state" is of type check_state but expression is of type character varying

Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

It seems like the body of the PUT mapping I am attempting to send is not being properly mapped to the proper Postgres enum, but I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite or cast the expression like the hint says using the Repo.save() method.

Comment: can you share Quad entity?

Comment: edited post to reflect Quad entity

Comment: You have an issue in the column definition, you need to define that column as an enum.

Comment: according to the [Spring Data JDBC docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc.entity-persistence.types), it seems like enums should automatically be mapped- am I misunderstanding this? My postgres enum type has the same naming as my Java enum.

Comment: I think the way column value is set by the JDBC is not correct, likely it's sending as VARCHAR but DB expect this as an enum.

Comment: Enums get mapped to their **name**, meaning to a string. They won't get mapped to a *postgres* enum. That would require a cast `'UNCHECKED'::check_state`. You'd have to create a custom `UserType` to support your enum. Which is why enums are often saved as `TEXT` instead of actual database `ENUM` columns, it's less work and often there's no significant difference.

Comment: Ah, seems like it can be done without `UserType` with the `stringtype` connection parameter, which makes it a less cumbersome (and more portable) solution. Good to know.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62188664/66686. Since it was so far only answered in the comments, I just put a proper answer in. Once that answer gets an upvote we may close this here.