# How to fix "Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of enum" error when inserting enum value?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, enums, postman

I'm trying to develop a simple CRUD-application,that receives data in the JSON-format,processes it, and puts it in a PostgreSQL table. One of the fields in the table, gender, is represented by an enumeration.

Here I am trying to add an entry using the Postman:

```
{
    "employeeId": 1,
    "firstName": "Ada",
    "lastName": "Lovelace",
    "departmentId": 3,
    "jobTitle": "Senior",
    "gender": "FEMALE",
    "dateOfBirth": "1815-12-10"
}
```

Here is the DAO-layer code:

```
@Override
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id, job_title, gender, date_of_birth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS gender), ?)";
    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, employee.getEmployeeId(), employee.getFirstName(), employee.getLastName(),
            employee.getDepartmentId(), employee.getJobTitle(), employee.getGender(), employee.getDateOfBirth());
}
```

As a result, I get: 500 Internal Server Error and

```
"PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO employees(employee_id, first_name, last_name, department_id, job_title, gender, date_of_birth) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CAST(? AS gender), ?)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of com.way.dto.Gender. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use."
```

Comment: This has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356750/java-postgres-enums-how-do-i-make-them-work-together-for-update). Besides, you should also post the database model for the employee's table.

Comment: I saw this question and the article indicated in the answer helped me in a similar situation. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What SQL type is the gender field?

In stead of passing in the enum, you could also pass in the string equivalent, for example `employee.getGender().name()` or `employee.getGender().toString()`

Comment: When creating the table, I created the type "gender" as an enumeration ... Everything works, thanks a lot

Comment: it's common for SQL wrappers to be confused by enums,  stringing them is the easiest fix.