# How to alter Postgres Enum type using JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I try to add values to a postgres enum type like this (removing the loop for the values):

```
      PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("ALTER TYPE my_enum_type ADD VALUE ?;");
      
      stmt.setString(1, "value");
      stmt.addBatch();
      stmt.executeBatch()
```

When I run that I get:

`Batch entry 0 ALTER TYPE my_enum_type ADD VALUE 'value' was aborted: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"`

googling I found out that it probably has to do with casting. I changed the query to:

`ALTER TYPE my_enum_type ADD VALUE ?::my_enum_type`

it gives the same error.

and

`ALTER TYPE my_enum_type ADD VALUE cast(? as my_enum_type)`

it fails with syntax error on `cast`

I worked around it by concatenating a string with the enum value and executing that, but there has to be a better way.

I am new to postgres, is there a simple way to work around it?

EDIT:
In response to comments and to avoid confusion:

1. [How do I make Java & Postgres enums work together for update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356750/how-do-i-make-java-postgres-enums-work-together-for-update) is about executing updates and not ALTER. The solution there is to cast to the target type, which I tried and did not work.

Solution:

Following Laurenz Albe's comment I ended up modifying my solution to:

```
        try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {

            PGConnection pgconn = conn.unwrap(PGConnection.class);

            for (String i : missingValues) { 

                stmt.addBatch("ALTER TYPE my_enum_type ADD VALUE '" + pgconn.escapeLiteral(i) + "'");
            }


            stmt.executeBatch();
        }
```

Comment: Try not using a batch, so just [execute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute--) (and remember to close your PreparedStatement when done).

Comment: You don't even need a `PreparedStatement` for this, a `Statement` is enough unless you intend to do something horrible with enums. I suggest you study harder though, because you've clearly missed the _entire_ point of batching.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356750/how-do-i-make-java-postgres-enums-work-together-for-update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters in statements can only be used with `INSERT`, `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE` and `VALUES`, but not with `ALTER TYPE`.

To find this limitation in the documentation, you have to know that a JDBC prepared statement in time leads to a “server-side prepared statement”, which in PostgreSQL can be created with the SQL statement `PREPARE`. [The documentation for `PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html#id-1.9.3.159.7) says:

> `statement`
>
> Any `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `MERGE`, or `VALUES` statement.

You'll have to construct the query string yourself. To avoid SQL injection, quote the string properly with the built-in methods:

```java
org.postgresql.PGConnection pgconn = conn.unwrap(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class);

String query = "ALTER TYPE my_enum_type ADD VALUE " + pgconn.escapeLiteral("value");

conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(query);
```

Comment: Thanks for the escape literal. I will use this. Only change is to substitute || with + in the string concatenation.

Comment: Thanks for the fix - I write too much SQL and too little Java.

Comment: Since Java 9/JDBC 4.3, the JDBC API also has a method [`enquoteLiteral(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html#enquoteLiteral(java.lang.String)) on the `Statement` object.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Interesting. I wonder if that covers all bases (like backslashes, if `standard_conforming_strings = off`).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe The PostgreSQL JDBC driver doesn't seem to have overridden the default implementation (which only takes into account SQL standard), so probably not.